# Postman não acha o UUID que esta na base de dados do MySQL

Tags: mysql, postman, uuid

Olá, fiz os testes de POST e GETALL no postman, e retornaram 'ok', eles funcionaram e visualizo as informações no mysql ou quando faz o GETALL no postman. Mas quando tento fazer a busca pelo id, ele nao encontra esse meu id. No codigo do projeto que vi esta igual, a unica diferença é que no video do YT é que ela usa postgresql e eu estou usando mysql. Nao sei se foi algo que digitei errado, ou se é alguma configuracao do mysql. Quem puder me ajudar ou me informar algo agradeço. Eu procurei na internet sobre, mas nao encontrei algo qeu ajudasse.

[Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqQgY.png)
[service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcNEf.png)
[Postman GETALL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02aCz.png)
[Postman GetById usei o 1 id do GetAll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6tEH.png)

Comment: Boas-vindas. Por favor, não duplique perguntas, siga as orientações [já passadas por outros membros na pergunta original](/q/588886/), para que você corrigir os problemas dela e ela poder ser reaberta, comentários podem ser feitos na pergunta original. **Nota:** [NÃO usar imagens para códigos e logs](/a/7817/). *Agradecemos a compreensão*.